# Is the Princess Tutu manga any different from the anime, and does it add anything to the story?

Tags: princess-tutu

Per my knowledge, Princess Tutu's anime adaptation came first and was remade into a manga later on. Does the manga of the show remain faithful to the anime, or are there differences between them? Does it add anything to the story?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [wikia](http://princesstutu.wikia.com/wiki/Princess_Tutu_manga) :

> The entire story of the manga is different from that of the anime with
>   absent characters, too. Focusing more on the ballet side of things
>   rather than the fairy tale elements that appeared in the anime, the
>   manga brings with it a fresh look at the setting of Princess Tutu.
>
> We could have listed all the differences between the manga and anime
>   but there are so many that it would serve no point and result in
>   telling the entire story.

So even though they share same name and have similar themes, they are so different as to be considered two different things.

Comment: Manga sounds less interesting.